# CANVAS: It is not possible to completely delete arc if using ctx.globalCompositeOperation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

First, I draw an arc with diameter at any position. I would then delete a circular area in another position so that it could cut the first arc, using ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out' and draw an arc and then set ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source- over'. I'll end up drawing a similar arc at the exact spot I just deleted.
Its two func i used to:

```
const eraseDot = (ctx, { x, y, size }) => {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    drawDot(ctx, { x, y, size, color: 'white' });
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
}
```

```
const drawDot = (ctx, { x, y, size, color }) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, size / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
};
```

My desired result is to draw 2 intersecting arcs (like how to draw 2 normal arcs but I want to clear the image area before drawing the 2nd arc). But it appears that there is a gap between the intersection of the 2 arcs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXcb1.png)

this means different erase and draw area sizes. please tell me the reason of this and how to solve it , thanks :

Comment: That's antialiasing. Almost all the pixels around your circle are semi-opaque. When use to do the compositing, they'll not clear entirely the pixel behind. But for what you're trying to do it's unclear why you'd use compositing at all  why can't you simply draw your 2 arcs one over the other exactly? If the shape must have some transparency, then either compose your path with both circles before calling `fill()`, either use a second canvas to draw the shape opaque and set the opacity later when drawing that second canvas on the main one.

Comment: i tried to draw opacity line  with a set of arcs with opacity. i tried 2nd canvas to draw strokes but it doesn't really suit my pj. I want to keep the stroke as a collection of arcs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What strokes? Could you show a mockup of what you want?